# uploading on dmcloud

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, video-streaming, httprequest

I am working on a website where I use DMCloud for streaming videos.
For now, I have a form which got some files input. I upload videos on my website, then I move the file to DMCloud with PHP, then I delete it.

It's kind of stupid, and make me lost lot of bandwidth.

On their doc, I have seen that : https://www.dmcloud.net/doc/api/api-upload.html
So I am trying to use it. I have set the action of my form on the url that the function returns me.
But every time I submit the form, dmcloud anwsers me : `{ "error": "missing file" }`

So how can I tell him, which document I want to upload on DMCloud ?
Can I send the request with ajax ?
Can I do multi-videos upload on the same form ?

Edit : Here is some code, but I do not think it can help.
I even dont know how to do it so, my code is stupid and useless and do not work ...
On my Controller :

```
$CloudKey=new CloudKey('503660c394a6f6067c0005c3','bb36a94fb64388417172d5f1f93453b3996627a5');
$CloudKey->file=$CloudKey->__get('file');
$action=$CloudKey->file->upload(array('status'=>true,"target"=>"http://www.carpediese.fr/?tamere=1"));
    $action=$action->url;
```

And on my view I got a basic form, with lot of inputs. With method="post" enctype="multipart/data", and the action which values as my `$action` var.

Comment: can you please share some code...

Comment: I edit! But I dont think my code will help. Because I dont know how to do it. And their documentation is not helpfull...

Answer (score 2):

PHP:

```
require_once 'CloudKey.php';

$cloud_key = new CloudKey('503660c394a6f6067c0005c3','bb36a94fb64388417172d5f1f93453b3996627a5');
$action_url = $cloud_key->file->upload(array('status'=>false,'target'=>'http://www.carpediese.fr/?tamere=1'))->url;
```

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?=$action_url?>">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

Comment: How can I have more than one file input in the form ?
And how can I have some file inputs that I dont want to upload on DMCloud ?

Comment: My point is, the only way to upload this way to DMCloud, is by getting a file input with name="file" ...
There are no others ways ?

Comment: @vekah Their API says nothing about uploading multiple files and from what I can see from their SDK it doesn't suggest it's possible. You could possible try adding multiple inputs with the name set to `file[]`.

Comment: With your second question, you'd need a separate form to do that. The one I provided posts all the `post` data to DMCloud. You can't have it both ways.